# asp.net application integrated with QuickBooks

Tags: asp.net, web, quickbooks, connector

I am using QuickBooks desktop version, i have created an asp.net application to integrate it with QuickBooks , but now i need to know how can i use the Web connector to integrate them.
do i need to create an asp.net webservice application? please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickBooks Web Connector is essentially a SOAP web service client that is installed alongside QuickBooks and polls your website asking "What have you got for me to do?". You feed it XML requests (e.g. `<CustomerAdd>...</CustomerAdd>` that it relays to QuickBooks. QuickBooks processes those requests and sends you back a response.

There's a good overview (and some technical details) on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector).

You should probably start by downloading the [QuickBooks SDK](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb). The SDK includes a few examples in this directory that would be helpful to you:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK12.0\samples\qbdt\c-sharp\qbXML\WCWebService
```

Once you have the basic structure of your SOAP web service laid out, everything is pretty simple. Whenever the Web Connector connects you just feed it qbXML requests. Here are some sample qbXML requests to take a look at:
 - [QuickBooks qbXML for adding a customer](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Customer) 
 - [QuickBooks qbXML for adding a received payment](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Received_Payment)

A full reference of all available qbXML requests is available via the [QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) guide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , already i downloaded the QuickBooks SDK, but i trying to use COM approach , i read this tutorial , could you please advice me if this will help ?
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/49505b57-bad0-4cef-90aa-f400a9e3cd98/c-net-application-with-quickbooks-desktop-edition.aspx

Comment: That tutorial is for building a Windows desktop application that integrates with QuickBooks - if you're building a Windows desktop app, that tutorial is fine. If you're building a website that you want to integrate with QuickBooks, you should use the Web Connector (or at least consider the mess that is Intuit Anywhere if you're a SaaS app).